# ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bitmap & ArrayList<>

Tags: android, arraylist, bitmap, android-gridview

I just don't understand why this exception is occurring. I have a custom adapter for my `GridView`, where I use a model to create a type `PhotoGridItem` class for my `ArrayList<PhotoGridItem>`, which is just a bunch of `Bitmap` images I pull from my SD card.

Compile time there are no errors, but when I run, I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bitmap cannot be cast to org.azurespot.cutecollection.PhotoGridItem`. Yet the line it points out is this: `PhotoGridItem photoGridItem = photos.get(position);`, where there are no `Bitmaps` by reference, the `photos` variable is a reference to `ArrayList<PhotoGridItem>` and the `get()` simply gets the `PhotoGridItem` object at that position.

Now... the items inside `PhotoGridItem` are all `Bitmap` (as shown by the model class), but that's not what Android Studio thinks (at compile time). It definitely considers `photos.get(position);` to be a PhotoGridItem object in my `ArrayList`. So I don't know why this exception is coming up or how to fix it.

I basically need a `Bitmap` for the lines that follow, this one: `holder.image.setImageBitmap(bm);` but it won't accept `photos.get(position);` (because at compile time it thinks it's a `PhotoGriditem` object!) So this feels like Android Studio is a little schizophrenic to me. Please help, thanks!

**GridViewPhotoAdapter**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

/**
* Created by mizu on 2/5/15.
*/
// package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/5/15.
 */
public class GridViewPhotoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public Context context;
    private int resourceId;
    private ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photos = new ArrayList<>();


    public GridViewPhotoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photos) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, photos);
        this.context = context;
        this.resourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.photos = photos;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid_view);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }



        PhotoGridItem photoGridItem = photos.get(position);

        Bitmap bm = photoGridItem.getImage();

        holder.image.setImageBitmap(bm);

        return row;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return photos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PhotoGridItem getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return photos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
    }

}
```

**PhotoGridItem**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 3/19/15.
 */
public class PhotoGridItem {

    private Bitmap image;

    public PhotoGridItem(Bitmap image) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

**PhotoTab.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class PhotoTab extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    File[] files;
    ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photoList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    public PhotoTab() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_tab, container, false);

        // with fragments, make sure you include the rootView when finding id
        gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid);
        adapter = new GridViewPhotoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.photo_grid_item,
                loadSDCard());
        // Set the Adapter to GridView
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // add the default icons remaining, to GridView, if less than 24 files on SD card
        for (int i = 0; i < (24 - photoList.size()); i++) {

            adapter.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            i++;
        }

        return v;
    }

    private ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> loadSDCard() {

        try {
            // gets directory CutePhotos from sd card
            File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File cutePhotoDir = new File(baseDir, "/Documents/CutePhotos");
            // lists all files in CutePhotos, loads in Files[] array
            files = cutePhotoDir.listFiles();


            for (File singleFile : files) {
                String filePath = singleFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                photoList.add(new PhotoGridItem(bitmap));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return photoList;
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
3218-3218/org.azurespot E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.azurespot, PID: 3218
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bitmap cannot be cast to org.azurespot.cutecollection.PhotoGridItem
            at org.azurespot.cutecollection.GridViewPhotoAdapter.getView(GridViewPhotoAdapter.java:57)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2791)
            at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1065)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1456)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2317)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1412)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1613)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1270)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6691)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5731)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The exception is (possibly) thrown because of `adapter.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder));`. `ArrayAdapter#add(T)` accepts a generic type. The compiler should complain if you make `GridViewPhotoAdapter` extend `ArrayAdapter<PhotoGridItem>` instead of `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first suggest you to add a type for your Array Adapter

```
public class GridViewPhotoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhotoGridItem> {
...
}
```

also in your PhotoTab.java

```
ArrayAdapter<PhotoGridItem> adapter;
```

After these two steps, you would probably get some errors or warnings now. If not, check this line in your PhotoTab.java

```
adapter.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder));
```

This line looks especially suspicious for me, because you're adding a Bitmap to and Array Adapter of PhotoGridItem. I guess what you want is:

```
adapter.add(new PhotoGridItem(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder)));
```

## Update

I would also suggest you not to pass in an ArrayList in your constructor, because ArrayAdapter already backed by an array. I didn't test the following code, but to illustrate my idea, here is the code:

```
public class GridViewPhotoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhotoGridItem> {

    public Context context;
    private int resourceId;

    public GridViewPhotoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, photos);
        this.context = context;
        this.resourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid_view);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }


        PhotoGridItem photoGridItem = getItem(position);
        Bitmap bm = photoGridItem.getImage();
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(bm);

        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
    }
}
```

And then in your PhotoTab.java:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_tab, container, false);

    // with fragments, make sure you include the rootView when finding id
    gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid);
    adapter = new GridViewPhotoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.photo_grid_item);
    // Set the Adapter to GridView
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.addAll(loadSDCard());

    // add the default icons remaining, to GridView, if less than 24 files on SD card
    for (int i = 0; i < (24 - photoList.size()); i++) {
        adapter.add(
            new PhotoGridItem(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder)));
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return v;
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I've been stuck on this for days. That worked what you said about adding `<PhotoGridItem>` to my `ArrayAdapter` and changing the `add()` to what you suggested. Only problem now, is I don't get images from my SD card, but rather the default placeholder image instead, but that is a separate problem now from this post. I have a question though, what would you suggest I pass in my constructor besides the `ArrayList<>`, or should I just leave it out?

Comment: Please check my latest code, it is probably due to your i++ inside a fori loop. I would suggest you to use addAll() method in ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Thanks, I changed everything! Although I still don't get any actual photos from my SD card. I did get rid of the `i++`, as I see it was iterating everything twice. Now I have the placeholder image 24 times though, which means the photos from my SD card are not retrieved. There should be at least 2 coming from the card. If you see anything obvious, let me know, otherwise I will take this issue up in a new question. But as far as this post, the error is gone! And you did it so fast. You're a genius. Can't thank you enough.